# How to avoid virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance

Seemed like a good strategy to compose my objects like this (as policies):

```
template<typename FluxType, typename SourceType>
class Model : public FluxType, public SourceType
{ };
//later in the code:
template<typename FluxType, typename SourceType>
class ConcreteModel : public Model<FluxType, SourceType>
{};
```

However, `FluxType` and `SourceType` are classes that use the same data. So I had used virtual inheritance:

```
class ConcreteModelProps{};
class ConcreteFlux : virtual public ConcreteModelProps
{};
class ConcreteFlux2 : virtual public ConcreteModelProps
{/*sligthly different implementation*/};
class ConcreteSource : virtual public ConcreteModelProps
{};
class DefaultSource2 
{/*no need for data*/};
```

That way I could compose my `ConcreteModel` with different `FluxType` and `SourceType` objects.

```
ConcreteModel<ConcreteFlux, DefaultSource2> /*or whatever*/.
```

The fact is that the the data that are defined in `ConcreteModelProps` are closely related to `ConcreteModel`. It seems to me that I'm doing at least something wrong. How can I make this design better? Preferably without the virtual inheritance?
thx, dodol

Comment: BTW, why [Smurf Naming](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html)?

Comment: May be the [CRTP pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) might help for your case, so you're able to mixin various implementations without needing virtual inheritance.

Comment: You did not **implement** virtual inheritance. The compiler does that. You **used** virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's simple: you are violating the [LISKOV Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) by having `ConcreteFlux` inherit from `ConcreteModelProps`; so it's only right you pay the price.

Now, if you *externalized* the data, you could be working with a saner model.

```
template <typename FluxType, typename SourceType>
class Model {
public: 
    typedef typename FluxType::DataType DataType;
}; // class Model

template <typename M>
class ConcreteModel: public M {
}; // class ConcreteModel
```

And then:

```
class ConcreteFlux {
public:
    typedef ConcreteModelProps DataType;
};

class ConcreteSource {
public:
    typedef ConcreteModelProps DataType;
};

template <typename Data>
class DefaultSource {
    typedef Data DataType;
};
```

With finally:

```
class ConcreteModel<Model<ConcreteFlux, ConcreteSource>> {};
```

Of course, this means that now all methods of `ConcreteFlux` and `ConcreteSource` need be passed the handle to `ConcreteModelProps` in each of their method. That's what *externalization* was about.